# $L^{p}$ estimate for $\Delta|\nabla u|$ on a manifold with bounded Ricci curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

This is a more advanced question than [Estimates of $\Delta|\nabla u|$ for harmonic function $u$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462276/520372) .
The Bochner formula and refined Kato inequality tells us that on a Riemannian manifold $(M^{n},g)$, if $u$ is a harmonic function in $B_{2}(x)\subset (M^{n},g)$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}|\nabla^{2}u|^{2}\leqslant |\nabla^{2}u|^{2}-|\nabla|\nabla u||^{2}=|\nabla u|\Delta|\nabla u|-Ric(\nabla u,\nabla u)\leqslant |\nabla^{2}u|^{2}.
$$
My question is how to obtain an analogous $L^{p}$ estimate for $\Delta|\nabla u|$. Let me fully state my question below.

For any $\delta>0$, does there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that if $(M^{n},g)$ is a manifold with $|Ric|\leqslant\epsilon$ and $u$ is a harmonic function in $B_{2}(x)\subset (M^{n},g)$ with
$$
\begin{split}
&|\nabla u|\leqslant 1,\\
&\int_{B_{2}}||\nabla u|-1|<\epsilon, \\
&\int_{B_{2}}|\nabla^{2}u|^{2p} < \epsilon
\end{split}
$$ for some integer $p\geqslant1$, then
$$
\int_{B_{1}}(\Delta|\nabla u|)^{p}<\delta \ ?
$$
This problem has been solved in the case of Euclidean space. See [Estimates of $\Delta|\nabla u|$ for harmonic function $u$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462276/520372) . But on a manifold with $|Ric|\leqslant\epsilon$, that method seems to not work, since we cannot get harmonicity for $\nabla u$ and apply Harnack inequality.

Also, it is easy when $p=1$, since we can multiply the Cheeger-Colding’s cutoff function (which has bounded laplacian provided lower bounds on Ricci, see https://doi.org/10.2307/2118589) and then integrate by parts. But for integer $p\geqslant2$, I can’t see how to do it.

Comment: The function $|\nabla u|$ is subharmonic, this should be the key.